# Converting line art to svg using only lines

Tags: image, svg, tiff

I would like to convert a black and white TIFF line art image to svg but I would like my svg to contain only lines or curves. My aim is to be able to simplify the svg path after vectorization.

My image looks like this:

[image]

I managed to convert it with [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) but potrace produce an svg with closed  paths which I cannot simplify with inkscape.

The converted image looks like this:

[image]

but if i try to simplify the path with Inkscape, I get this:

[image]

Is there a way to force potrace not to close paths or are there softwares that would allow me to convert my file to an svg with only open paths ?

The code to convert the tif to svg is (assuming my file is test.tif and that I am using Linux):

```
tifftopnm test.tif
potrace -s test.pnm
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think what you need is a center line trace. Potrace can't do that. Check out this repo (https://github.com/jnweiger/inkscape-centerline-trace). This should do the trick.

Comment: This may be an option as well https://cleversomeday.wordpress.com/2014/03/04/rrcenterline/

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this but the inkscape plugin needs autotrace which I can not install on my mac at the moment.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? See also http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39810/line-art-to-svg-path-conversion

Comment: @DavidDomain  CentreLineTrace now 404s . Could it have moved [here](https://github.com/fablabnbg/inkscape-centerline-trace)?

Comment: @Mawg autotrace http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/ has a centerline option.